# How to handle exceptions in python conceptually?

Tags: python, exception

in python it is common to define user-defined exceptions so they can return some user-defined test/output/whatever when an error happened in a user-defined class. But I wonder, if there is a good practice to handle exceptions for a given class in python? In detail, I have the following questions:

1. Should all the class-related exceptions go into the file that defines the python class, or should they go into a specific file?
2. Should exceptions be defined for any conceivable case of things that should rise an exception, or is it 'ok' to just define a general exception for a class and to print out details of where and what happened in the wrong way by giving some additional text?
3. I would appreciate if someone could post an example of how a user-defined exception could/should look like, so to see the reason why it is a good thing to define your own specific exception class.

Thanks
  Alex

Comment: I would look at how Python does this by default. It has a class hierarchy such that all input/output related errors use the same exception class. I've drawn a blank on other examples hence why this is a comment. I try to only write specific exception classes when it makes sense to else there is no need to fog up the clean exceptions that python gives by default. Also these specific exceptions I typically define in the same class file of where they are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. File-level organisation of Python programs isn't particularly interesting, except when you're doing maintenance. The module-level organisation is much more important as it determines the API (at least at `import` time), so make sure your exceptions are in the module that uses them.

   A common setup is to export all the exceptions of a package from the root of that package, so you can say `from foo import Foo, FooError, BarError`. Whether the definitions live in the same file can be hidden by the module system.
2. Depends entirely on how fine-grained you expect to catch the exceptions. Often, though, I find that the built-in exceptions (`ValueError`, `TypeError`, etc.) are fine-grained enough. For specific things that might go wrong in your package, you might add one or several exceptions.
3. How's about...

   ```
   class ParseError(Exception):
       def __init__(self, parser_input, line, column):
           self.input = parse_input
           self.line = line
           self.column = column

       def __str__(self):
           # format the exception message, showing the offending part of
           # self.input and what the parser was expecting.
   ```